# Splash UI doesn't start on windows

Tags: python, docker, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I've setted splash on docker with Docker Toolbox & Docker Quickstart Terminal. It gives this output:

```
$ docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
2018-02-27 14:29:21+0000 [-] Log opened.
2018-02-27 14:29:21.129146 [-] Splash version: 3.2
2018-02-27 14:29:21.136203 [-] Qt 5.9.1, PyQt 5.9, WebKit 602.1, sip 4.19.3, Twisted 16.1.1, Lua 5.2
2018-02-27 14:29:21.138036 [-] Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
2018-02-27 14:29:21.139606 [-] Open files limit: 1048576
2018-02-27 14:29:21.140590 [-] Can't bump open files limit
2018-02-27 14:29:21.263294 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':1117575427', '-screen', '0', '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
2018-02-27 14:29:21.962490 [-] proxy profiles support is enabled, proxy profiles path: /etc/splash/proxy-profiles
2018-02-27 14:29:22.400764 [-] verbosity=1
2018-02-27 14:29:22.402173 [-] slots=50
2018-02-27 14:29:22.403916 [-] argument_cache_max_entries=500
2018-02-27 14:29:22.406959 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)
2018-02-27 14:29:22.410192 [-] Server listening on 0.0.0.0:8050
2018-02-27 14:29:22.415698 [-] Site starting on 8050
2018-02-27 14:29:22.419534 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7ff34b2557f0>
```

I follow then the instructions of Splash guide:

> Splash UI provides an easy way to try scripts: there is a code editor for Lua and a button to submit a script to execute. Visit http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (or whatever host/port Splash is listening to).

But I can't open the address.
From the log:

```
00:19:47.225391          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 0 on port 26 of controller 'SATA'}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:19:47.225391          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 0 on port 27 of controller 'SATA'}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:19:47.225391          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 0 on port 27 of controller 'SATA'}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:19:47.225391          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 0 on port 28 of controller 'SATA'}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:19:47.225391          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 0 on port 28 of controller 'SATA'}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:19:47.226373          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 0 on port 29 of controller 'SATA'}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:19:47.226373          ERROR [COM]: aRC=VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001) aIID={85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={No storage device attached to device slot 0 on port 29 of controller 'SATA'}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:19:47.233242          ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89} aComponent={SessionMachine} aText={This machine does not have any snapshots}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
```

I can't recognize time of logging because of the strange format. Can someone tell where is the problem for not opening splash UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, and I report here because the guide is little misleading about for a beginner...
It suggests:

> Splash UI provides an easy way to try scripts: there is a code editor for Lua and a button to submit a script to execute. Visit http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (or whatever host/port Splash is listening to).

A person that doesn't know Docker may think that it, by default, is available at 127.0.0.1. In fact, being a virtual machine, it have his proper IP address, that may be different from localhost. So you must insert XX.XX.XX.XX:port instead, substituting to XX the correct location of the vm, and the port you've setted.